# Iphone work out if string is a UK Postcode

Tags: iphone, ios, regex, postal-code

In my app before I send a string off I need to work out if the text entered in the textbox is a UK Postcode. I don't have the regex ability to work that out for myself and after searching around I can't seem to work it out! Just wondered if anyone has done a similar thing in the past?

Or if anyone can point me in the right direction I would be most appreciative!

Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia has a [good section about this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom#Validation). Basically the answer depends on what sort of pathological cases you want to handle. For example:

> An alternative short regular expression from BS7666 Schema is:
>
> ```
> [A-Z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Z]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}
> ```
>
> The above expressions fail to exclude many non-existent area codes (such as A, AA, Z and ZY).

Basically, read that section of Wikipedia thoroughly and decide what you need.

Answer (score 3):

for post codes without spaces (e.g. SE19QZ) I use: (its not failed me yet ;-) )

```
^([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z])))) [0-9][A-Za-z]{2})
```

if spaces (e.g. SE1 9QZ) , then:

```
^([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z])))) {0,1}[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can match *most* post codes with this regex:

```
/[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}\s?[0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]{1,2}/i
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Which means... `A-Z` one or two times (`{1,2}`) followed by `0-9` 1 or two times, followed by a space `\s` optionally `?` followed by `0-9` one or two times, followed by `A-Z` one or two times.

This will match some false positives, as I can make up post codes like `ZZ00 00ZZ`, but to accurately match all post codes, the only way is to buy post code data from the post office - which is quite expensive. You could also download free post code databases, but they do not have 100% coverage.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will give a false negative on valid postcodes such as "WC1E 6BT"

Comment: @RichardGroves you could modify like this: `/[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9][0-9A-Z]?\s?[0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]{1,2}/i` to cover your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has some regexes for UK Postcodes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom#Validation